# git using wrong SSH key for different projects even with proper config file

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh

I'm trying to set up 3 different SSH keys for 3 github accounts.
My SSH config file is:

```
    # GitHub progOne
Host progOne
HostName github.com
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeyChain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/progOne_id_ed25519
IdentitiesOnly yes

# GitHub progTwo
Host progTwo
HostName github.com
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeyChain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/progTwo_id_ed25519
IdentitiesOnly yes

# GitHub progThree
Host progThree
HostName github.com
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeyChain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/progThree_id_ed25519
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

My remotes:

```
git@progOne:my_git_user/my_github_project_name.git
git@progTwo:my_git_user/my_github_project_name.git
git@progThree:my_git_user/my_github_project_name.git
```

I added keys to ssh agent using command:

```
 `ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/progOne_id_ed25519` (for rest keys by analogy)
```

When I'm executing `ls -al ~/.ssh` I see all of them. But when I'm trying to check ssh connection for each project, I see wrong git user.

I have found way when it works as expected:
When I'm adding corresponding ssh key in project terminal like this:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/progOne_id_ed25519
```

Then it works (for each project!). BUT it works only in this terminal window and after rebooting I need to add keys to ssh agent again.

OS: MacOS 12.4

Comment: "But when I'm trying to check ssh connection for each project, I see wrong git user." - - how are you checking? It looks as if whatever's setting up those ssh sessions is ignoring your .ssh/config and using only the agent protocol. Programs looking for an ssh agent have a few different ways of finding one, some of them configured in the file I suspect yours of refusing to use; that NIH attitude tends to make the kind of mess you're in.

Comment: On macOS, make sure you *do not* run ``eval `ssh-agent` `` or similar in terminal setup files.

Comment: @torek I used eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" as described in github manual https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Comment: @jthill I'm using  ssh -T git@github.com (from the same github manual above)

Comment: Try `ssh -T git@progOne`. By the way, if you add the user to your configs you don't have to type it every time.

Comment: @jthill yes, you are right. That was the problem. Thanks everybody!

Comment: The GitHub docs are for non-mac setup: on the Mac, your Terminal windows are launched with an ssh agent already running. Running a new one means that ssh-add run in the Terminal window doesn't communicate with the other Terminal windows. It's not that it doesn't work at all, it's that it defeats the mac's fancy setup.

Answer (score 1):

There wasn't any issue actually. I just incorrectly checked connection.
I used `ssh -T git@github.com` instead of `ssh -T git@my_host`.